# jetpack compose Backhandler: How to make the backhandler send a route with argument + the navcontroller.popbackstack

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to leave a screen and also eliminate a possibility of same command happening thus the reason why im using backhandler to eliminate double command as in the following code:

```
BackHandler {
    navController.navigate(Screen.Inbox.passAction(Action.NO_ACTION))
}
```

but another problem occurs. I end up hitting back button and ends up in a loop of navigating between point A and B. since point B doesnt get popBackStacked

Answer (score 0):

From oficial [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation):

```
// Pop everything up to the "home" destination off the back stack before
// navigating to the "friendslist" destination
navController.navigate("friendslist") {
    popUpTo("home") 
}
```

or

```
// Pop everything up to and including the "home" destination off
// the back stack before navigating to the "friendslist" destination
navController.navigate("friendslist") {
    popUpTo("home") { inclusive = true }
}
```